# starred return statements in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is regarding the following code:

```
def foo(*args):
    return *args # syntax error

def bar(*args):
    return 0, *args # ok

def foobar(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    return args

print(bar(1,2))
print(foobar(1,2))
print(foobar(1))

>>> (0,1,2)
>>> (1,2)
>>> 1
```

is there why reason why `foo`, rather than being invalid Python code, does not have the same behaviour as `foobar`? I guess I would also be willing to accept `foo` producing a singleton tuple i.e. `(1,) = foo(1)`. Any insight into this would be appreciated!

Comment: Even your second example become possible only in python 3.8 ([see #7](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#other-language-changes)). Generally you can return either single value or tuple. Your starred expression is useless there, you can just return `args` cause actual unpacking happens when you're assigning return of function to multiple variables.

Comment: > I guess I would also be willing to accept foo producing a singleton tuple i.e. (1,) = foo(1) -- Why not just return `args` from `foo`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght of course I know this, this is just a minimal example (perhaps too minimal). I was hoping to get a behaviour like `foobar` just by using the * operator on return. With the idea that if an int is supplied, an int is returned, if multiple ints are supplied a tuple of ints is returned. Actually, the answers given explain things well enough. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @BenedictWilkinsAI, this behavior is completely useless, cause to call this function you will need to write additional conditions to check return type.

Comment: @OlvinRoght In general yes. However, I use these kinds of functions in interactive notebooks where I already understand the return type (i.e. no check is required) and I am using the function in a different way in each case (single int vs multiple ints). Granted the use case is pretty niche...

Comment: @BenedictWilkinsAI, it's not good from architecture side. Better to rebuild app avoiding such as tricks as soon as possible, cause it will definitely create problems in future.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Noted, I am only using them for prototyping usually for ML related stuff write a notebook, get results and forget about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, usefulness of such construct is rather dubious. Esp. since you end up returning `tuple` of unpacked values... so why not return the `tuple` itself?

If you really wanted to make this work, you could, starting with Python 3.5 say:

```
return (*args,)
```

In line with [PEP-448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). This unpacks `args` items into tuple that is to be returned.

And starting with [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#other-language-changes), you could drop the enclosing parenthesis:

> Generalized iterable unpacking in yield and return statements no longer requires enclosing parentheses...

```
return *args,
```

Your `bar()` does essentially the same using that generalized unpacking behavior as described in the linked PEP, just having leading item in the tuple.

Comment: Funniest thing is that both `return (*args,)` and `return *args,` are equal to simple `return args` 

Comment: The idea was that I want to keep the return type "consistent" with the supplied arguments - return an int if a single int is supplied, return a tuple of ints if multiple ints are supplied. I often find this cleaner, the examples of where its more convenient are a bit convoluted... Still, thank you for the explanation and reference.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the explanation, I believe the comments made above have addressed it.
I wrote the following code and got it to return (1,). You can also follow the suggestion and simply remove the * in front of args in your original code as the comments suggest.

```
def foo(*args):
    return *args, 

def bar(*args):
    return 0, *args # ok

def foobar(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    return args

print(bar(1,2))
print(foobar(1,2))
print(foobar(1))
print(foo(1))
```

Here is a picture of the output. I am using Python 3.8
[image]

It returns the singleton tuple, as you desire. Is this what you needed?

Comment: Try to replace `return *args,` with `return args` and see the difference.